# Tag SharePoint pages with "I like it" tag programmatically

Tags: powershell, client-object-model, tags

I need to tag a lot of pages with the tag `I like it`.

Is there any way of doing it programmatically? (i.e. PowerShell)

Answer (score 1):

`Reputation` class from `Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel` namespace (**CSOM** assembly `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll`) contains the following method:

```
public static ClientResult<int> SetLike(ClientRuntimeContext context, string listID, int itemID, bool like)
```

The following example demonstrates how to set Like for a List Item using SharePoint 2013/Online CSOM in PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles")


Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}


$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$ctx.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$result = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation]::SetLike($ctx,$listId,$ItemId,$true)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$ctx.Dispose()
```

Comment: First answer I've come across to clearly indicate that the "like" equivalent for managed CSOM resides in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.dll assembly and not a "CSOM version" of Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel. This isn't as obvious as it should be in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

See the solution implemented in C# [here](http://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2014/04/01/like-or-unlike-a-list-item-programmatically/).

You should either use the [Reputation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.reputationmodel.reputation.aspx) class:

```
Reputation.SetLike(listID, itemID, true);
```

or via updating the item’s LikesCount and LikedBy fields:

```
SPFieldUserValueCollection likedBy = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, item["LikedBy"].ToString());
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser("YOURDOMAIN\\USERNAME");
SPFieldUserValue newUser = new SPFieldUserValue(web, user.ID, user.Name);
likedBy.Add(newUser);
int likes = likedBy.Distinct().Count();
item["LikesCount"] = likes;
item["LikedBy"] = likedBy;item.SystemUpdate(false);
```

You can find another discussions of the same issue [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85552/programmatically-like-a-blog-post-with-reputation-setlike-sharepoint-2013) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84279/programmatically-like-a-blog-post).

The PowerShell equivalent of the first option should be:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles")
[Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation]::SetLike($listId, $itemId, $True)
```